# Theory of probabilities

Tags: probability-theory

There are two baskets:

The first contains 5 plums and 10 grapes, the second one contains 3 plums and 12 grapes.

One fruit of the first basket is extracted and put into the second one.

What is the probability that the fruit taken from the second basket will be plum?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 events:

- Event 1 - you take out a piece of fruit from basket 1 and put it in basket 2,
- Event 2 - you take out a piece of fruit from basket 2.

**Step 1**: You move 1 fruit from the first basket into the second one.

Let's name the fruits: fruit $1$, fruit $2$, ..., fruit $15$. Let us assume that you are equally likely to take all fruit out (and not that you are more likely to grab a plum because plums are larger in size). Then the probability of taking fruit $j$ is $\frac{1}{15}$ for any $j = 1,2,..,15.$ Because you have $5$ plums and $10$ grapes, you sum up the probablities over each group:

1. $\frac{1}{15}*5 = \frac{1}{3}$ probability to take out a plum,
2. $\frac{1}{15}*10 = \frac{2}{3}$ probability to take out a grape.

**Step 2**: How many fruit do we have of each sort in the second basket?

1. Case 1: $4$ plums and $12$ grapes in your second basket, so a total of $16$ fruit in your second basket.
2. Case 2: $3$ plums and $13$ grapes in your second basket, so a total of $16$ fruit in your second basket.

**What is the probability of choosing any fruit in your second basket?**

> $\frac{1}{16}$

**Step 3**: Find the probability of taking a plum and grape by summing up within each fruit group.

**Step 4**: By the law of total probabilities, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability, you have to weigh your outcomes by the probability of each outcome (Case 1: take out plum, Case 2: take out grape) of your Event 1 (Take out piece of fruit from basket 1).

The probability of taking a plum from basket 2 is the probability of taking a plum out in Case 1 plus the probability of taking a plum out in Case 2, weighed by the probability of Case 1 and Case 2, so

$\mathbb{P}(\text{Take out plum of basket 2}) = \frac{1}{3}*\mathbb{P}(\text{Take out plum if Case 1 happened})+ \frac{2}{3}*\mathbb{P}(\text{Take out plum if Case 2 happened}).$

All you have to do now is find these 2 probabilities the same way that I described for Event 1.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks for the information, was not familiar with these standards.